# How to get a tuple for a variadic function with only one argument in Scala3?

Tags: scala, inline, variadic, scala-3

In the code below Scala3 views the argument list as a tuple except if there is only one argument. What is the best way to convert the single argument into a tuple here?

```
import scala.compiletime.*
import scala.deriving.*

object Variadic {

  trait Converter[T]:
    def convert(x: T): String

  given Converter[Int] with
    def convert(x: Int) = x.toString

  given Converter[String] with
    def convert(x: String) = x

  inline def arg2String[T <: Tuple](x: T): List[String] =
    inline erasedValue[T] match
      case _: EmptyTuple => Nil
      case _: (t *: ts) =>
        val arg = x.asInstanceOf[t *: ts]
        summonInline[Converter[t]].convert(arg.head) :: arg2String[ts](arg.tail)


  inline def makeString[T <: Tuple](x: T): String = arg2String(x).mkString(",")

  def test: String = {
    val x = makeString(3, 4, "aa")
    println(x)
    
    val y = makeString("s") // Does not compile
    println(y)
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the arguments in another set of parenthesis like: `val y = makeString(("s"))` or `makeString((3, 4, "aa"))`

Comment: Make `makeString` overloaded method. One has an evidence <:< Tuple, one has not

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, the extra parenthesis do not work.

Comment: @SwiftMango, thanks! It is working for object methods, but somehow is not working for overloaded extension methods.
```
  extension(s: String)
    inline def add2String[T <: Tuple](x: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Tuple): String = s + arg2String(x).mkString(",")
    inline def add2String[T](x: T): String = s + arg2String(Tuple(x)).mkString(",")

   
    y.add2String(6,7, "test") // Does not compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just overload `makeString()`?

```
inline def makeString[T <: Tuple](x: T): String = arg2String(x).mkString(",")
inline def makeString[T](x: T): String = summonInline[Converter[T]].convert(x)
```

Here's a [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nGSKlQoASRa7u6v0rELf2g) to demonstrate.

Comment: I didn't know we can overload with different type parameter bound now. It's more hectic in Scala 2.

Comment: Unfortunately overloading is not working in extensions. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r6pOVSurRaqga0pWMRxvbg

Comment: @michkhol Looks like it didn't work because the auto tupling doesn't work in extension method. It works when you wrap with parentheses: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/R3Yp3gFsSzClZb4Q7k4HBQ You should avoid using auto tupling anyway because they are discussing about removing that

Comment: @SwiftMango Auto tupling works if there’s no polymorphic methods in the extension. Removing auto tupling I think is a really bad idea, because variadic functions is a very useful feature.